# Pandas, Python - Assembling a Data Frame with multiple lists from loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Using loop to collect target data into lists from JSON file. These lists are organized as columns and their values are organized; thus, no manipulation/reorganization is required. Only attaching them horizontally.

```
#Selecting Data into List
i=1
target = f'{pathway}\calls_{i}.json'
with open(target,'r') as f: #Reading JSON file
    data = json.load(f)

    specsA=('PreviousDraws',['DrawNumber'])
    draw=(glom(data,specsA)) #list type; glom is a package to access nested data in JSON file.
    print(draw)

    for j in range(0,5):
        specsB=('PreviousDraws',['WinningNumbers'],[f'{j}'],['Number'])
        number=(glom(data,specsB)) #list type; glom is a package to access nested data in JSON file.
        print(number)

    #Now assembling lists into a table using pandas
```

The resulting lists from the code above are as followed below:

```
#This is from variable draw
[10346, 10345, 10344, 10343, 10342, 10341, 10340, 10339, 10338, 10337, 10336, 10335, 10334, 10333, 10332, 10331, 10330, 10329, 10328, 10327]

#This is from variable number 
['22', '9', '4', '1', '1', '14', '5', '3', '2', '8', '2', '1', '4', '9', '4', '4', '3', '13', '7', '14']
['28', '18', '16', '2', '3', '17', '16', '13', '11', '9', '8', '2', '9', '19', '7', '13', '7', '23', '21', '17']
['33', '24', '21', '4', '9', '20', '27', '19', '23', '19', '19', '7', '19', '30', '19', '27', '19', '32', '26', '21']
['35', '30', '28', '11', '21', '23', '33', '26', '35', '37', '27', '12', '20', '31', '22', '34', '22', '36', '27', '25']
['36', '32', '33', '19', '29', '38', '35', '27', '37', '38', '32', '30', '22', '36', '33', '39', '36', '38', '30', '27']
```

Expected Data Frame table after assembly:

```
Draw  |  Number[0]  |  Number[1]  |  Number[2] ...
10346 |  22         |   28        |
10345 |  9          |   18        |
10344 |  4          |   16        |
10343 |  1          |   2         |
10342 |  1          |   3         |
```

My attempt at assembling the table: Organize as dictionary with Series, below:

```
dct = {'DrawNumbers':pd.Series(draw),
        'Index1':pd.Series(number),
        'Index2':pd.Series(number),
        'Index3':pd.Series(number),
        'Index4':pd.Series(number),
        'Index5':pd.Series(number)
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(dct)
print(df)
```

Actual result - incorrect due to last list's value being repeated in table's row. So far, only Index5 column is correct, while all index columns are incorrectly represented with index 5's values.

```
    DrawNumbers Index1 Index2 Index3 Index4 Index5
0         10346     36     36     36     36     36
1         10345     32     32     32     32     32
2         10344     33     33     33     33     33
3         10343     19     19     19     19     19
4         10342     29     29     29     29     29
5         10341     38     38     38     38     38
6         10340     35     35     35     35     35
7         10339     27     27     27     27     27
8         10338     37     37     37     37     37
9         10337     38     38     38     38     38
...        ...      ...    ...    ...    ...    ...
```

Also had tried to change the data type of the number from string to int, but having repeated errors attempted that. Either way, I am stuck and would like to request for assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are overwriting the `number` variable in the loop, so is no longer available at the end of each iteration, I add a solution adding the column Index in each iteration.

```
# create an empty dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()

#Selecting Data into List
i=1
target = f'{pathway}\calls_{i}.json'
with open(target,'r') as f: #Reading JSON file
    data = json.load(f)

    specsA=('PreviousDraws',['DrawNumber'])
    draw=(glom(data,specsA)) #list type; glom is a package to access nested data in JSON file.
    print(draw)

    # insert the draw to the dataframe
    df['DrawNumbers'] = draw

    for j in range(0,5):
        specsB=('PreviousDraws',['WinningNumbers'],[f'{j}'],['Number'])
        number=(glom(data,specsB)) #list type; glom is a package to access nested data in JSON file.
        print(number)
        # insert each number to the dataframe
        df[f'Index{j}'] = number
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `number` is a nested list:

```
number = list(map(list, zip(*number))) # this transposes the nested list so that each list within the list now corresponds to one row of the desired df
pd.DataFrame(data=number, index=draw)
```

This will output the df in the desired format. Of course you can go ahead and label the columns as you like, etc.